# QEMU, Virsh and SMBIOS tables edit

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, bios, virsh

I am currently running qemu-kvm on an Ubuntu server box and I use libvirt with Virsh to create, manage, start and stop VMs.

I edited VM's XML configuration through virsh edit command to change CPU model and set up SMBIOS data by specifying **bios** and **system** details.

I saw that qemu should support -smbios type=X tables edit as well, like smbios table 3 and 4. However if I try to edit XML through Virsh by adding **processor** tag, the XML is not validated and thus rejected.

Is there any way to pass SMBIOS tables 3 and 4 to QEMU through virsh or should I instead avoid using Virsh at all and go straight to qemu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<qemu:commandline>` domain XML tag.

For example:

`<qemu:commandline>
   <qemu:arg value='-option-rom'/>
   <qemu:arg value='path/to/my.rom'/>
</qemu:commandline>`

For more information, read [here](http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/04/how-to-pass-qemu-command-line-options.html)